# Using select * and count(*) together in a query in SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server, database

I have a table with 12 columns.

I need a query for computing `COUNT(*)` and selecting all the columns.

I mean I want to have these two queries just in one query:

```
select * 
from mytable 
where OneOfTheColumns = something;

select COUNT(*) 
from mytable 
where OneOfTheColumns = something;
```

Conditions and tables are the same.

Can I do this?

Thanks a million.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [a window  function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461.aspx) for that

```
select *,
       count(*) over () as total_count
from mytable 
where OneOfTheFields = something;
```